# Redeploy Google Cloud Function from command line using Source Repositories

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-source-repos

I have a fairly simply Google Cloud Function that I'm deploying from Cloud Source Repositories.

I'm using the Google Cloud Shell as my development machine.

When I make updates to the function as I'm developing, I use the CLI to push updates to my Source Repository.  However, running the `gcloud functions deploy ...` command from the command line doesn't seem to *force* GCF to pull in the latest source.

Occasionally, the `deploy` command after pushing new source code will simply state "Nothing to update." (which is incorrect.)

More often, it will go through the deployment process but the function will still run the previous version of the code.

When this happens the only way I can get the function to update is to use the dashboard, "Edit" the function, and then hit the Deploy button (even though I didn't change anything.)

Am I forgetting to do some kind of versioning or tagging that is required?  Is there a way to force the CLI to pull the most current commit from the source repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`--source=SOURCE`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--source) [gcloud functions deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy) option to point to a source repository instead of the current directory (the default):

> `--source=SOURCE`
>
> Location of source code to deploy. Location of the source can be one
>   of the following three options:
>
> - Source code in Google Cloud Storage (must be a `.zip` archive),
> - Reference to source repository or,
> - Local filesystem path (root directory of function source).
>
> Note that if you do not specify the `--source` flag:
>
> - Current directory will be used for new function deployments.
> - If the function is previously deployed using a local filesystem path, then function's source code will be updated using the current
>     directory.
> - If the function is previously deployed using a Google Cloud Storage location or a source repository, then the function's source code will
>     not be updated.
>
> The value of the flag will be interpreted as a Cloud Storage location,
>   if it starts with `gs://`.
>
> The value will be interpreted as a reference to a source repository,
>   if it starts with `https://`.
>
> Otherwise, it will be interpreted as the local filesystem path. When
>   deploying source from the local filesystem, this command skips files
>   specified in the `.gcloudignore` file (see [`gcloud topic
>   gcloudignore`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) for more information). If the `.gcloudignore` file
>   doesn't exist, the command will try to create it.
>
> The minimal source repository URL is:
>   `https://source.developers.google.com/projects/${PROJECT}/repos/${REPO}`
>
> By using the URL above, sources from the root directory of the
>   repository on the revision tagged `master` will be used.
>
> If you want to deploy from a revision different from `master`, append
>   one of the following three sources to the URL:
>
> - `/revisions/${REVISION}`,
> - `/moveable-aliases/${MOVEABLE_ALIAS}`,
> - `/fixed-aliases/${FIXED_ALIAS}`.
>
> If you'd like to deploy sources from a directory different from the
>   root, you must specify a revision, a moveable alias, or a fixed alias,
>   as above, and append `/paths/${PATH_TO_SOURCES_DIRECTORY}` to the URL.
>
> Overall, the URL should match the following regular expression:
>
> ```
>   ^https://source\.developers\.google\.com/projects/
>   (?<accountId>[^/]+)/repos/(?<repoName>[^/]+)
>   (((/revisions/(?<commit>[^/]+))|(/moveable-aliases/(?<branch>[^/]+))|
>   (/fixed-aliases/(?<tag>[^/]+)))(/paths/(?<path>.*))?)?$
> ```
>
> An example of a validly formatted source repository URL is:
>
> ```
>   https://source.developers.google.com/projects/123456789/repos/testrepo/
>   moveable-aliases/alternate-branch/paths/path-to=source
> ```

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  Thank you!  I guess I assumed it would pick up the settings from when the function was first deployed but I see how that was incorrect.

Comment: can the ${MOVEABLE_ALIAS} be in a format "feature/xxx-NNN-yyy"? I mean with the "/" inside?